# Unable to add project to github repository

Tags: git, github

I having a project already which is part of git repository. I need to add it to github repository.

I first created a repository in github by selecting new repository. It then gives me the following options to upload

```
or create a new repository on the command line
echo "# xx" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/xxxxxx/xx.git
git push -u origin master

…or push an existing repository from the command line
git remote add origin https://github.com/xxxxxx/xx.git
git push -u origin master
```

When i try either option it seems to not upload the files to https://github.com/xxxxxx/xx.git

Instead it looks like not able to remote repository and trying to commit to existing repository that i pulled it from. Not sure how to point it to the remote repository . If I do git branch on the project folder i can see branches of the existing git repository

What am i missing

Comment: Is it giving you an error message?

Comment: Initially it gave messages like refs are missing etc but then after i commited, I saw the commits were in the existing registry when i did git history

Comment: Are there commits on GitHub that aren't on your local machine?

Comment: There are any commits that are applied on Github yet. The repository folder is empty

Comment: The commits got applied to the source repository

Comment: So then what happens when you run those last two commands?

Comment: Please include actual error messages (cut and paste text). See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to change the `origin`. Try the following commands.

- Change remote URL to new GitHub repo:
  `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`
- Verify the remote URL is correct:
  `git remote -v`
- Push to new repo:
  `git push origin master`

Edit:
The problem was that a **proxy** was configured on the system.
After **removing the proxies from .gitrc** (after backing up) pushing worked without errors:
 `git config --global --unset https.proxy`
 `git config --global --unset http.proxy`
(or manually editing `.gitrc`)

Comment: The first two commands worked. The third command gave error : failed to push some refs to https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git

Comment: And if you force using `git push -f origin master`?

Comment: same error. Do i need to do a git init or git add . or git commit ?

Comment: The error in both cases also says src refspec master does not match any

Comment: Yeah try adding a file and commit at least a single change and re-running the push. Probably the master branch isn't initialized yet on the GitHub repo.

Comment: I tried git init, then git add . and also tried git add README.md. Then when I try git push origin master, i get the same error

Comment: When I do git remote -v , It shows me the remote repository path

Comment: What's the output of `git branch`?

Comment: What confuses me is when I do git remote -v , it shows the remote registry path but when I execute git commit -m "first commit" , I get message On branch branch name . nothing to commoit

Comment: git branch list me the branch name of the source repository

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185856/discussion-between-laurens-deprost-and-tom).